# Trying to create "Add Category" field. Laravel error column not found:

Tags: laravel-5.6

[image]

I'm trying to create Add Category field in project. When I click for creating Category, appeared this problem:

[image]

How to create this column in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new field in DB through migration. There are two options first you can rollback your table using `php artisan migrate:rollback` and add the column in the migration `$table->boolean('published)` and then run the command `php artisan migrate`

Note:This will remove all data from DB
if  you doesn't want to Remove existing data you can create new migration using command

```
php artisan make:migration --table=categories
```

and add `$table->boolean('published)` in up function and in down funtion `$table->dropColumn('published)`

for more information you can check [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations)

Comment: Thank you @rocco.thapa, it's very helpful answer.
For first step i rollback in composer (php artisan migrate:rollback)
For Second step i migrate it. (php artisan migrate)
now all is working great :)